# CSV file to flat array with materialized path

Tags: php

I have CSV file which contains a list of files and directories:

```
Depth;Directory;
0;bin
1;basename
1;bash
1;cat
1;cgclassify
1;cgcreate
0;etc
1;aliases
1;audit
2;auditd.conf
2;audit.rules
0;home
....
```

Each line depends on the above one (for the depth param)

I would like to create an array like this one in order to store it into my [MongoDB collection with Materialized Paths](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-MaterializedPaths%28FullPathinEachNode%29)

```
$directories = array(
  array('_id' => null,
        'name' => "auditd.conf",
        'path' => "etc,audit,auditd.conf"),
  array(....)
);
```

I don't know how to process...
Any ideas?

**Edit 1**: 
I'm not really working with directories - it's an example, so I cannot use FileSystems functions or FileIterators.

**Edit 2**:
From this CSV file, I'm able to create a JSON nested array:

```
function nestedarray($row){
    list($id, $depth, $cmd) = $row;

    $arr = &$tree_map;

        while($depth--) {
         end($arr ); 
         $arr = &$arr [key($arr )];
    }

    $arr [$cmd] = null;             

}
```

But i'm not sure it's the best way to proceed...

Comment: I first tried to build an nested array like {dir1: [ dir11 : [ file111, file112 ], dir12 : [...]} and then apply a recursive function, but I could't succeed in this way

Comment: The array is already flattened .. Your example is also very specific.  Does the depth ever go 0,1,2,1 ?  That would complicate things.

Comment: Yes, the array is flattened (I didn't edit my title). And yes, the depth can go.. deeper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, I think (it worked in my test, at least, with your data).  Note that this code doesn't do much error checking and expects the input data to be in proper order (i.e. starting with level 0 and no holes).

```
<?php

$input = explode("\n",file_get_contents($argv[1]));
array_shift($input);

$data = array();
foreach($input as $dir)
{
    if(count($parts = str_getcsv($dir, ';')) < 2)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if($parts[0] == 0)
    {
        $last = array('_id' => null,
                      'name' => $parts[1],
                      'path' => $parts[1]);
        $levels = array($last);
        $data[] = $last;
    }
    else
    {
        $last = array('id' => null,
                      'name' => $parts[1],
                      'path' => $levels[$parts[0] - 1]['path'] . ',' . $parts[1]);
        $levels[$parts[0]] = $last;
        $data[] = $last;
    }
}

print_r($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way to go would be to not store your data in CSV format, as it's the Wrong Tool For The Job.

That said, here you go:

```
<?php
$lines = file('/path/to/your/csv_file.csv');
$directories = array();
$path = array();
$lastDepth = NULL;

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list($depth, $dir) = str_getcsv($line, ';');

    // Skip headers and such
    if (!ctype_digit($depth)) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($depth == $lastDepth) {
        // If this depth is the same as the last, pop the last directory
        // we added off the stack
        array_pop($path);
    } else if ($depth == 0) {
        // At depth 0, reset the path
        $path = array();
    }

    // Push the current directory onto the path stack
    $path[] = $dir;

    $directories[] = array(
        '_id' => NULL,
        'name' => $dir,
        'path' => implode(',', $path)
    );

    $lastDepth = $depth;
}

var_dump($directories);
```

**Edit:**

For what it's worth, once you have the desired nested structure in PHP, it would probably be a good idea to use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), or some other format to store it to disk again, and get rid of the CSV file.  Then you can just use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get it back in PHP array format whenever you need it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really, but it did't work as expected :-(

Comment: How did it not work as expected?  If you feed it the input you put in your question, it provides the same output you said that you wanted.